# Is it possible to load multiple partial view at a time using Thread or Task?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I have 4 partial views on a single view page which only display a list of records each. Can it be possible to load all partial views at a time using thread or task?

Answer (score 0):

You'd rather use an AJAX call to load those partials in parallel. This would allow you to load the initial page quickly and then trigger parallel AJAX calls to populate the partials. During the execution of those AJAX calls the user won't have the browser freezed and be able to still work with the rest of the page.

There's not much sense in using threads or tasks on the server as they won't bring any benefit here. Now this being said there are some optimizations that can be done on the server as well. Let's suppose that the data that is bound to those partials is independent. This means that it can be fetched in parallel from the corresponding data source(s) without having to wait the other data. So basically think of a view model with a complex property for each of the partials. Now you could use an [`asynchronous controller`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee728598%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) to load each property of this view model in parallel.

So instead of having the following controller action:

```
public class HomeController: Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        MyViewModel model = new MyViewModel(); 
        model.Foo = GetFooFromDbSynchronously();
        model.Bar = GetBarFromDbSynchronously();
        model.Baz = GetBazFromDbSynchronously();
        return View(model);
    }
}
```

you would have this:

```
public class HomeController: AsyncController
{
    public void IndexAsync()
    {
        AsyncManager.OutstandingOperations.Increment(3);
        BeginGetFooFromDbAsynchronously(foo => 
        {
            AsyncManager.Parameters["foo"] = foo;
            AsyncManager.OutstandingOperations.Decrement(1);
        });

        BeginGetBarFromDbAsynchronously(bar => 
        {
            AsyncManager.Parameters["bar"] = bar;
            AsyncManager.OutstandingOperations.Decrement(1);
        });

        BeginGetBazFromDbAsynchronously(baz => 
        {
            AsyncManager.Parameters["baz"] = baz;
            AsyncManager.OutstandingOperations.Decrement(1);
        });
    }

    public ActionResult IndexCompleted(Foo foo, Bar bar, Baz baz) 
    {
        MyViewModel model = new MyViewModel(); 
        model.Foo = foo;
        model.Bar = bar;
        model.Baz = baz;

        return View(model);
    }
}
```

The view will of course be the same, taking the main view model and rendering the partials for each property. The benefit here is that the information for each partial is retrieved independently of the others which will speed up the page load time. So the total page load time won't be the sum of the load times of the 3 operations, but it will be the slowest of them.